# What's causing this background-image to display "incorrectly" in Opera and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, opera

I know this is something I'm probably doing wrong, so please don't incinerate me for the thread title.

I'm trying to put together a small personal website using HTML 5/CSS3.  I've checked with the w3c validator and the site and CSS file fully conform according to the validator (However the validator has a warning attached that it might not be perfect).

I'm not sure how to explain it without a picture, so here's a comparison of Chrome/Opera/Firefox:
[image]

So, you can sorta see how in Chrome the background image is in one non-repeating piece, whereas in Opera/Firefox the image has, oddly, been broken up and placed slightly differently.

I'm confident this is due to an error on my part, but I've had no luck at all figuring out why the image is being mangled in Opera and Firefox.

Here's the CSS that's relevant to this issue:

```
/* Content Pane */         
.content
{           position: absolute;
            left: 220px;
            width: 800px;
            top: 80px;
            min-height: 550px;
            background-color: rgba(8,12,42,0.85);
}

/* Headers */
.content hgroup 
{
            background: url("Header_Flat.png") no-repeat left top;
            min-height: 38px;
            padding-left: 28px;
            text-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFA9FF;
            color: Black;   
            text-decoration: none;  
}

.content hgroup h1 
{
            display: block;
}

.content hgroup h3
{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;
            left: 20px;
            text-shadow: 0 0 6px #AFF9FF;
}

.content hgroup h4
{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;
            left: 20px;
            font-size: xx-small;    
            text-shadow: 0 0 6px #AFF9FF;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<hgroup> 
    <h1>New Site!</h1> 
    <h3>Now with Bloom!</h3> 
    <h4> - Posted Tuesday, May 11th 2010</h4> 
</hgroup>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

I changed the CSS a bit, and it halfway-fixed the image (I don't understand why) and the bad alignments (I hadn't yet noticed those).

[image]

The changed CSS defs are as follows:

```
/* Headers */
.content hgroup 
{
            background: url("Header_Flat.png") no-repeat left top;
            min-height: 38px;
            position: relative;
            text-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFA9FF;
            color: Black;   
            text-decoration: none;  
}

.content hgroup h1
{
            position: relative;
            left: 28px;
}

.content hgroup h3
{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;
            left: 48px;
            text-shadow: 0 0 6px #AFF9FF;
}

.content hgroup h4
{
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            top: -12px;
            left: 48px;
            font-size: xx-small;    
            text-shadow: 0 0 6px #AFF9FF;
}
```

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove the text-shadow attributes?

Comment: In FireFox, press CTRL+SHIFT+J to open error console. Clear everything. Now view your page (or refresh it) and see what does the warning tab contain. Does FireFox complain about not being able to parse CSS or HTML?

Comment: Firefox has absolutely nothing in its error console after clearing and refreshing the page

Comment: Do you have a URL? It would be helpful to see the whole context in Firebug.

Comment: http://sukasa.kicks-ass.org/ It's just a home connection, so it may take 1-2 seconds to load the whole site.

Comment: Something else: Don't forget to (re)set the padding and margins on all elements. And i usually better to give elements margin and/or padding instead of relative positioning. Latter can lead to unwanted effects like overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it: You need to give hgroup `display: block`.

EDIT: Keep in mind that most browsers don't know the new HTML5 elements yet thus they are missing all default style.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the parent element of positioned child elements to `relative` to make the positioning work.

```
hgroup{
  position: relative;
}
```

Your `h1` needs a width and height, otherwise `display: block` is a little pointless imho.

These are the two things which jump out at me the most :)

Comment: I removed the css def for the h1 since display:block's the default anyways and it was leftover, did nothing.  I re-added it the way it was and tried your first suggestion, did nothing.  Removed the h1's css again and checked, still nothing.

Comment: You only need to set the parent element to `position: relative` if you have **absolute** positioned elements in it, that are supposed to be positioned relative to that parent element. Other relative positioned elements don't need that.

Also there is absolutely no reason to need to set width and height of a block element.

Comment: Ah fair enough, it was something that I picked up from the CSS validator, perhaps I'm thinking of floated elements needing a width and height

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look in Chrome and Firefox and they're both displaying the same as your error pic.

Take a look here: [HTML5 browser support checklist](http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus#target-selector), seems that Firefox and Opera don't support all HTML5 attribute yet, so invariably there will be some weird problems. The browsers don't know all the default styles of HTML5 elements yet, so more reason for strange errors. Can't think of any other fixes other than DavidYell's answer, eveything seems fine in the CSS.

Comment: When you say they're displaying the same, do you mean the same as their individual reference pictures or both the same as a single "erroneous" picture?

Comment: Sorry, they're messed up in all the browsers, they are not one picture, but chopped up.

Answer (score 0):

The *background image alignment* CSS is not ready on all browsers.
It's as if you only had:

```
.content hgroup 
{
background: url("Header_Flat.png") no-repeat;
etc.
```

Since `hgroup` has no set size your background image will float around when you're using different browsers at different zooms.

If you are able to set `hgroup`'s size you can design your .png the size of hgroup, transparent and with the blue streaks aligned top left.

I am also looking forward to full CSS3 support in all browsers.

There are so many effects that look so cool in some browsers and then just look mangled in others. I personally prefer 1)Firefox 2)Safari